# stepping through a function line by line

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghci

This user guide:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html

advertises:

> Execution can be single-stepped: the evaluator will suspend execution
>   approximately after every reduction, allowing local variables to be
>   inspected. This is equivalent to setting a breakpoint at every point
>   in the program.

Yet, I can find nothing in the document that tells me how to do that.  Under the heading:

> 2.5.2. Single-stepping

It describes how to step from breakpoint to breakpoint.  But I don't want to have to set a breakpoint on every line.  Was the advertisement false or is there a way to step through a program line by line?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a terminology problem. When you use `:step` the debugger **creates** a breakpoint "approximately after every reduction". You don't have to set a breakpoint on every line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

```
ghci> :step function_name arg1 arg2
...
...
ghci> :step   
...
...
ghci> :step
```

If you forget the function arguments, then you will get the cryptic error message:

```
<interactive>:138:1:
    No instance for (Show (String -> Double))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (String -> Double))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

...which might lead you to tear your hair out.  And if you want to skip to the end:

```
ghci> :continue
```

Comment: That error message doesn't really have anything to do with stepping, though. You get the same error if you pass too few arguments to a function on the main prompt. It's telling you that it cannot print the resulting partially applied function. (The suggestion to add an instance is bogus).

Comment: "It's telling you that it cannot print the resulting partially applied function."  Yes, I figured that out--but it took me awhile.  For some reason, I always want to type :step my_func and leave out the args.  I added that error message to my post in case someone else does that.

Answer (score 6):

After having set and reached a breakpoint, you can call `:step` from the debugger.

There are other single-step possibilities. Typing `:help` once at a breakpoint would tell you more about what you can do.

Comment: Okay, that's a work around--but that isn't what was advertised.  Thanks for looking.